# Creating a dataset that indicates what areas to show in a Crystal Report

Tags: sql, visual-studio, crystal-reports

CR for VS 13_0_22 -

I'm creating a report with the data in a group header and footer to then be exported to PDF.

I create a dataset using a xml file with sql query, and then adding it to the report in VS2017.

The goal here is for some areas of the report to be shown depending on configuration. I was given this instructions:

```
Area1 - 0 , Area2 - 1 Area3 - 0

"Select 0,1,0,"
```

to create a new dataset  that does it.

Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you connect directly to the database?

Comment: I added 3 columns in one of the querys and then added one of them to the report. Then adding a formula to supress if that field from my columns is present. But i'm unsure if that's the goal here. It's meant for the user to able to select what he needs to be shown in a web page so this method probably won't work for that.

Comment: Maybe you want do pass parameters to the report then, instead of using the query. The way to do that depends on your tech. Do you write code to show the report or just connect directly to the database?

Comment: Sorry, i'm not sure what you mean about connecting directly. I use the xml file with queries to get that data from sql which then creates a data set.

I added this to my dataset :
select 
'0' as AREA_tabl2
'1' as AREA_tabl3,
'1' as AREA_tabl4 

When creating a parameter I set type as number, and list of values as static. Then AREA_tabl2 as Value Field and 0 and 1 in the value drop down list. 
But i'm stuck here as when I try to export the report the error "Parameter values are missing appear"